# How to call my web API and display data in GridView?

Tags: c#

Here is my API `localhost:51549/API/student/`

I want it to be displayed in my form when the button is clicked as a data grid.
I have tried:

```
private  void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:51549/");
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/student").Result;
          
    dataGridView1.DataSource = response; 
}
```

Note: my student controller basically calls a DLL to do the operations.

Comment: Hey, you have registered the domain name "localhost" for my IP address 127.0.0.1. It returns my data! Please undo that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the content of the response to the DataSource:

```cs
dataGridView1.DataSource = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```